# NSData not working correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdata

```
NSData *myRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"&site=%@&key=%@",tmpSite,tmpKey)];
```

Why is this not working ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give us a hint to what the problem is by providing a error message? :)

Comment: MyRequest is not containing tmpsite & tmpkey ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is that you are assigning `NSString` instance to variable of `NSData` type. Try this:

```
NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&site=%@&key=%@",tmpSite,tmpKey];
NSData* d = [s dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; //or any other encoding!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData *myRequest = [[NSString stringWithFormat:(@"&site=%@&key=%@",tmpSite,tmpKey)] dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

You can't just mix the two classes like that.